# Problem displaying figure captions from array while looping

Tags: captions, arrays, foreach

I'm attempting to generate multiple Figures using the code below. However, I'm having a problem with `\caption{\questions(\plotNum)}`. The error I receive is `Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 129.`. Could someone please indicate what exactly the problem is and how to fix it? Perhaps there is a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newarray\questions
\readarray{questions}{
    Question1&Question2&Question3
}

\foreach \plotNum in {0,...,2} {
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Plots/pie_all_data_\plotNum.png}
        \caption{\questions(\plotNum)} % PROBLEM HERE
        \label{pie_all_data_\plotNum}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that your array only contains 3 elements, while you're trying to reference 12. Also, `\plotNum` starts with `0`, while `\questions(\plotNum)` only references properly when `\plotNum` is greater than `0`. Apart from that, the problem here arises from the fact that `\caption` writes content to an external file (for possible usage in a LoF), which should be handled carefully. Are you going to create a LoF?

Comment: Very true. That was a copy and paste error from simplifying the code for this question. I was not planning to make a list of figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that `\caption` writes content to an external file (for possible usage in a List of Figures/LoF), which should be handled carefully. If you're not going to create a LoF, you can just call `\caption` with an empty optional argument:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{arrayjob,graphicx,pgffor}

\begin{document}
\newarray\questions
\readarray{questions}{%
  Question01&Question02&Question03&%
  Question04&Question05&Question06&%
  Question07&Question08&Question09&%
  Question10&Question11&Question12
}

\foreach \plotNum in {1,...,12} {
  \begin{figure}[h!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Plots/pie_all_data_\plotNum.png}
    \caption[]{\questions(\plotNum)}
  \end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Note that I'm cycling `\plotNum` from `1` through `12`, since array indexing does not start with `0`. I've also added sufficient entries inside `\questions` to match your loop cycle.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has been annoying me for at least a couple of hours now.